# Log file is not rolling in windows 2008 server

Tags: java, spring, log4j, windows-server-2008

When I tested in AIX server 7.0 and windows7, rolling file by log4j works well. but It does not work in windows 2008 server. 
the follow xml file is my log4j.xml

```
    <appender name="dailylogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="File" value="D:/gscmmb/logs/daily_logfile.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%c][%L][%p] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

file list in the aix server and windows7:

- daily_logfile.log
- daily_logfile.log.2013-09-02-14

file list in the windows 2008 server:

- daily_logfile.log

First I suspected the file permisison. so I had run a simple java program that test the 2008's file permission, but all permissions of directories were allowed.